# Alguien puede resolverme un botón con una consulta Mysql y php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqldb

Estoy en un proyecto que necesito un botón de los registros de los últimos 6 meses, os paso el archivo de configuración ya que me da error, abajo hay mas código pero el que tengo el problema es en este apartado llamado historial, si alguien supiese os lo agradecería, mi problema es que le intento asignar un botón para que me haga la consulta de los últimos 3 meses pero directamente me saca todos los historiales no logro conseguir sacar esa parte del codigo.

```
/* Alejandro Historial Paciente  */
?>
<div style="margin-top:-50px;">       
    <table width="100%">          
    
    <?php
        require("../alejandro/conexiones.php");
       // require("../alejandro/conexiones.php");
        $link=Datosbd();

        if( ! isset($_GET["recetas"]))
            {
                $Texto="Historial";                    
            }

        if(  isset($_GET["recetas"]) && $_GET["recetas"]==1 )
            {
                $Texto="Recetas";                    
            }

        if(  isset($_GET["recetas"]) && $_GET["recetas"]==2 )
            {
                $Texto="Recetas Gafas";                    
            }

            $UrlDato1="/societe/soc.php?socid=".$_GET["socid"];
            $UrlDato2="/societe/soc.php?socid=".$_GET["socid"]."&recetas=1";
            $UrlDato3="/societe/soc.php?socid=".$_GET["socid"]."&recetas=2";
            $UrlDato4="/alejandro/imprimirHistorial.php?id_paciente=".$_GET["socid"];
            $UrlDato5="/societe/soc.php?socid=".$_GET["socid"]."&recetas=4";
            $UrlDato6="/societe/soc.php?socid=".$_GET["socid"]."&recetas=5";
            $UrlDato7="/societe/soc.php?socid=".$_GET["socid"];
            $UrlDato8="/societe/soc.php?socid=".$_GET["socid"];
            $UrlDato9="/societe/soc.php?socid=".$_GET["socid"];
            $UrlDato10="/societe/soc.php?socid=".$_GET["socid"];

            if(  $_GET["action"] <> "edit")
            {
    ?>



<tr>
            <td><h3><?php echo $Texto ?> Paciente</h3>
            
                <a class="butAction" href="<?php echo $UrlDato1 ?>">Historial</a>
                <a class="butAction" href="<?php echo $UrlDato2 ?>">Recetas</a>
                <a class="butAction" href="<?php echo $UrlDato3 ?>">Recetas Gafas</a>
                <a class="butAction" href="<?php echo $UrlDato5 ?>">Facturas</a>
                <a class="butAction" href="<?php echo $UrlDato6 ?>">Informes</a>
                <a class="butAction" href="<?php echo $UrlDato7 ?>">Ultimo Mes</a>
                <a class="butAction" href="<?php echo $UrlDato8 ?>">Ultimos 3 Meses</a>
                <?php
                    if(! isset($_GET["recetas"]))
                    {
                        echo '<a class="butAction" href="'.$UrlDato4.'" target="_blank">Imprimir Historial</a>';

                    }
                ?>
                
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <?php 
            }
            if( ! isset($_GET["recetas"]) && $_GET["action"] <> "edit")
            {

        ?> 
        
        
        <tr>

        <!--
            <td width="100%"> <textarea disabled="" id="historial" name="historial" rows="10" style=" width:100%;">
            <?php 
                    /* Saco el historial del paciente */
                        
                        $sqlHistorialPaciente="Select * FROM historial WHERE id_paciente=".$_GET["socid"]." order by fecha desc";
                        
                        $queryHistorialPaciente= mysqli_query($link,$sqlHistorialPaciente);

                          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryHistorialPaciente))
                             {

                                  $phpdate = strtotime( $row["fecha"] );      
                                 setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
                                 $dia=strftime('%d',$phpdate);
                                 $mes=strftime('%B',$phpdate);
                                 $anyo=strftime('%Y',$phpdate);

                                 //echo $row["fecha"]." \n \n".utf8_decode($row["descripcion"])." \n \n";
                                 echo $dia." ".$mes." ".$anyo." \n \n".utf8_decode($row["descripcion"])." \n \n";
                             }
```

Comment: La continuación del código esta abajo ya que no me dejaba publicar tanto código

Comment: Hola, por favor lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) además échale un ojo a [ejemplo minino verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y podrías pasarte por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Luego edita tu pregunta para evitar que sea cerrada

Comment: Aqui puedes encontrar lo que necesitas. https://github.com/CarlosCordova1/consumiento-api-rest-con-jquery

si tienes dudas, contactame y te ayudo.